# unable to connect to wlan on gentoo

Tags: networking, wifi, gentoo

Could've worded that title better but anyways,

I recently did a gentoo install, networking worked fine during the livecd stage so my network card is probably supported.
Ethernet works with no problem.

[image]

```
Bringing up interface wlp2s0
Caching network module dependencies
Staring wpa_supplicant on wlp2s0 ...
Succesfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Starting wpa_cli on wlp2s0
Backgrounding... ...
Warning: net.wlp2s0 has started, but is inactive
Warning: netmount will start when net.wlp2s0 has started
Starting local ...
```

It shows an error like this whenever I boot, I also can't ping anything other than local host.

I already enabled the options that relate to ath10k on my kernel config
[image]

```
$grep -i "ath10' .config | sed 's/  /\n---  /g'
CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE="ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin
---ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board-2.bin
__ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
---regulatory.db
---regulatory.db.p7s"
CONFIG_ATH10K=y
CONFIG_ATH10K=y
CONFIG_ATH10K=m
```

```
<*> Atheros 802.11ac wireless cards support
<M> Atheros ath10k PCI support
```

[image: I even tested with including and excluding any combination I find]
I even tested with including and excluding the bin files I find in the firmware files

[image]It can even see access points

```
$iw wlp2s0 scan | grep -i ssid
SSID: *********
...
SSID:*************
```

[image]

Iwconfig also seems to not recognize it as a wireless device
[image]

```
$iwconfig
lo               no wireless extensions
enp1s0f1 no wireless extensions 
sit0            no wireless extensions 
wlp2s0      no wireless extensions
```

I even used iw_supplicant on it already
[image]

```
$cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
network={
ssid="*********"
#psk="***********"
psk="******************************"
}
```

The driver even gets recognized
[image]

```
Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8377 802.11ac Wireless network adapter
...
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

And shows up as "up" in opperstate.

My conf.d/net does have the same ip for wlp and enp1 which is copied from the gentoo handbook if that's an issue.

Comment: Please do not post images of ext, for many reasons (including that not all in the community can see images to read them, and they are no searchable by the site's search feature). Either copy/paste, or take the time to transcribe the text. You will greatly improve your chances of someone helping you if you present your problem in the format(s) as indicated by the site's Community Guidelines. Please edit your question  to make it text, or text + images.

Comment: I already ran dhcpcd and my net conf follows the same format as Netifrc

Comment: Have you emerged `linux-firmware`?

Comment: Yes, I also just recently tested it with genkernel and the same errors happen so it's probably not with my kernel